# "Integrity constraint violation: Duplicate entry" Despite using firstOrCreate

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Currently trying to seed the database with a lot of data. It's very possible that I will get the same record twice so I thought to use firstOrCreate to make sure I don't try to save it again with the same id. This is the code

```
<?php

foreach($transformedData as $item) {
    $itemId = $item['id'];
    unset($item['id']);
    CarPart::firstOrCreate(['id' => $itemId], $item);
}
```

However it is throwing this error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '10232010' for key 'car_parts.PRIMARY'
```

I really don't understand why it's happening since firstOrCreate should prevent it from happening and it's because of duplicate enteries for the primary key not some other unique field.

dd from first $item

```
{
"id": 10232010,
"name": "MAZDA 3 BM 14-18, MOTOR",
"comments": "TYPE SH\r\nFRA STEL NR : JMZBM622611324260\r\n90000KM\r\nIMPORT/EN/HI/637413\r\n6 MDR REKLM.RET\r\nGL ENHED I BYTTE",
"notes": "KOLLEGA 30000\r\nINDK17000\r\n\r\nSØNDERJYSK 30000+++   LOSE   5/10-22",
"quantity": 1,
"price1": 32000,
"price2": 27200,
"price3": 44800,
"condition": "B2",
"oem_number": "SH",
"shelf_number": "PÅ VEJ",
"year": 2018,
"car_part_type_id": 3574,
"dismantle_company_id": 50,
"kilo_watt": 0,
"transmission_type": "",
"item_number": "G08361",
"car_item_number": "IMP022",
"item_code": "34730010",
"car_vin_code": "",
"engine_code": "",
"engine_type": "2.2TDI",
"kilo_range": 90,
"alternative_numbers": "",
"color": "",
"car_first_registration_date": "1900-01-01T01:24:00"
}
```

Migration for car_parts table

```
  Schema::create('car_parts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('car_part_type_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('dismantle_company_id')->constrained();

        $table->string('name');
        $table->longText('comments');
        $table->longText('notes');
        $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
        $table->string('car_first_registration_date');
        $table->integer('kilo_watt')->unsigned();
        $table->string('transmission_type');

        $table->string('item_number');
        $table->string('car_item_number');
        $table->string('item_code');
        $table->string('condition');
        $table->string('oem_number');
        $table->string('shelf_number');
        $table->float('price1');
        $table->float('price2');
        $table->float('price3');
        $table->string('car_vin_code');
        $table->string('engine_code');
        $table->string('engine_type');
        $table->string('kilo_range');
        $table->integer('year');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->string('alternative_numbers')->nullable();

        /* $table->string('dito_number_fk'); */

        /* $table->foreign('dito_number_fk')->references('dito_number')->on('dito_numbers')->onDelete('cascade'); */
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: What is the primary key column name?

Comment: could you please `dd($item)` before firstOrCreate and show us the data?

Comment: Assume you have id column and it must be AUTO_INCREMENT , so maybe you have to write last row like: CarPart::firstOrCreate($item); Check example https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models
Also if you need to keep special id - make/add another column , like id_item which is NOT AUTO_INCREMET and save that special $itemId there

Comment: @nice_dev primary key is just id

Comment: @Vit problem is that the id I get has to be the unique identifier that defines what the action of firstOrCreate should be

Comment: @meowzart Can you show migration file for this table?

Comment: @nice_dev have added it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out the problem. I had a global scope on the CarPart model so if a part would not match that requirement the "first" of the "firstOrCreate" would fail but then it would try to create the existing record.

It's working fine with eloquent withoutGlobalScope